# php time string to time offset from start of day

Tags: php, datetime, time-format

does php have any built-in functionality to convert a readable `time-string` (stressing `time`, `not datetime`) with the same relaxed format allowed by strtotime to a offset in seconds from beginning of day.

php `DateTime` or `strtotime` seem to only work with date-times
like "12-07-13 10:30:00"

what i really want is  a generic time (no date) like "10:30pm" or "23:30 or "13-15" etc.

should become something like "81000", "84600", "47700"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need a built-in function to do:

```
$seconds = strtotime('10:30 pm') - strtotime('00:00');
var_dump($seconds);
```

Comment: You can even use 'midnight' instead of '00:00' if you like.